# .submit () isn't including hidden fields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post, submit

Binding a jQuery `.submit()` post to a `dropzone file upload` complete handler results in all the correct data being sent, except it's missing the hidden input fields. Code is all `php` and `jquery/js`

Can't find anything about why these would be excluded.

All hidden fields are in the form, and have both name and id filled

```
<pre>
<code>
<form id="payments" method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" class="form-horizontal" >

<input type="hidden" name="transID" value="<? if(isset($values['transID'])){echo $values['transID'];}else{ echo $transID; } ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="transID" value="<? if(isset($values['transID'])){echo $values['transID'];}else{ echo $transID; } ?>" />
<input type="hidden" id="pdflink" name="pdflink" value="<? if(isset($values['pdflink'])){echo $values['pdflink'];} ?>" />
<input type="button" name="btnSubmit" value="Submit PDF & Payment(s)" onclick="this.disabled" id="btnSubmit" class="col-md-6 btn btn-primary raised" />
</form>
<script>
$('#upload').fileupload({

// This element will accept file drag/drop uploading
autoUpload: true,
dropZone: $('#drop'),
limitMultiFileUploads:1,
maxNumberOfFiles: 1,
fileInput: $('#upl'),
url: 'acctfilesupload',
dataType: 'text',

// This function is called when a file is added to the queue;
// either via the browse button, or via drag/drop:
add: function (e, data) {

var tpl = $('<li class="working"><p></p></li>');

// Append the file name and file size
tpl.find('p').text("Submitted File: " + data.files[0].name).append('  <i>' + formatFileSize(data.files[0].size) + '</i>');

// Add the HTML to the UL element
data.context = $(ul).html(tpl);


// upload the file once it is added to the queue
$('#btnSubmit').click(function(){
var jqXHR = data.submit();})
},

progressall: function (e, data) {
var progress = parseInt(((data.loaded / data.total * 85)+ 15), 10);
$('#uploadprogress').css('width', progress + '%').html("&nbsp;&nbsp;Uploaded: " + progress + '%');
    },
done: function(e, data){
var r = data.result;
if (r.lastIndexOf("\\\\FShost\\Accounts", 0) === 0) {
$('#pdflink').val(r);
$('#payments').submit();
} else {
alert(r);
$('#btnSubmit').prop('disabled',false);
$('#uploadprogress').css('width','15%').html("&nbsp;&nbsp;Uploaded: 0%");
}
}
}).bind('fileuploadsubmit', function (e, data) {
data.formData = {
name: $('#uploadname').val(),
memberid: $('#memberidupload').val(),
transid: $('#acctfilesubID').val(),
amount: $('#AmountOwed').val()
};
});

</script>
</code>
</pre>
```

Comment: I guess hidden fields are not submitted -  try `visibility:none` while building the form

Comment: Your `hidden` fields needs to be inside your `form`

Comment: Does it have `name` attribute?

Comment: share some code with us please.

Comment: @JitendraPurohit hidden fields get submitted, `disabled` ones do not

Comment: topsy-turvy ;), Thanks @AlexAndrei

Comment: I fixed your question - the code was hidden due to not being indented. You also need to show that the `<form>` tag contains the given code - otherwise the form will not contain the submitted fields.

Comment: Thank you @StampyCode, all of the relevant code is now there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FOUND IT!  the problem is a hard limit with php in the max number of fields that can be submitted in one form.  It just happened to be that the last field to be submitted with that limit also happened to be the last field before hidden fields would appear in the POST